# Poisson Distribution - Optimistaion

Tags: probability, proof-verification, poisson-distribution

> A store offers a new seasonal product featured. Let $N$ be the random variable
>   which means the number of clients who come to the store during the season, where
>   $N \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(19)$. It is estimated that the probability that a customer buys the new product is $0.38$
>   regardless from a customer to another.
>
> a) It is assumed here that the store has an unlimited supply of product. Random variables $X$ and $Y$ are such that
>
> $X$: The number of customers who purchase the product ;
>
> $Y$: The number of customers who do not buy the product.
>
> Are the variables $X$ and $Y$ independent ? Justify .

**My answer:** I think they are dependent, because there is a fixed number of costumers, and when the number of buyers changes, the number of non buyers changes too.

> b) The store has a profit of 63 million for each unit sold. Each unsold unit
>   should be stored for next year at a cost of 38 million.
>
> Determine what the number of units stored should be to
>   maximize its average profit.

**My answer:** Let's start with the pdf of Poisson distribution.

$p_x(k)=\displaystyle\frac{e^{-\alpha}\alpha^k}{k!}$ , for k=0,1,...

$\alpha=19$

$p_x(k)=\displaystyle\frac{e^{-19}19^k}{k!}$ , for k=0,1,...

Now I don't know how to relate my 0.38  to the equation I just came up with...

Since 38% of the people buy, I need to first estimate how many costumers I'll have with the Poisson distribution, then assume that 38% only will  buy. So to maximize my profits, let's say there is 100 costumers estimated, I'll only put 38, so I'll sell every one of them. But I don't know how to apply this logic to the problem.

Your help is really appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Part A**

**Given:** We have customers arriving at a constant average rate of $19$ per season, each at a time independent of the arrival of the previous customer, *and* each customer has an independent probability for being a purchaser of $0.38$.

*Note:* Although the seasonal counts, of purchasers and non-purchasers, are *conditionally* dependent, *for a given total seasonal count* of customers, that is *not* what you were asked.

**Hint:** A Poisson distribution is, by definition, that of the count of events occurring in an interval (of time and/or space) if these events occur with a *constant average rate* and *independently* of the time since the last event.

Put them together to identify the distributions of the seasonal counts of purchasers and non-purchasers, and assess whether they depend on each other or not?

Part B should then fall into place.

---

Formula you *should* know:

The total count is Poisson distributed with rate $19$ per season.   So $N\sim\mathcal {Poiss}(19)$, which implies that: $$\mathsf P(N=x+y) = \dfrac{19^{(x+y)}~\mathsf e^{-19}}{(x+y)!} \quad\Big[x\in\Bbb N, y\in\Bbb N\Big]$$

For a given total seasonal count, the count of purchases will be conditionally binomial distributed with rate $0.38$ (can you justify?).   So $X\mid N\sim \mathcal {Bin}(N, 0.38)$, which implies that: $$\mathsf P(X=x\mid N=x+y) = \dfrac{(x+y)!~{(0.38)^x~(0.62)^y}}{x!~y!}\quad\Big[x\in\Bbb N, y\in\Bbb N\Big]$$

Now

- $\mathsf P(X=x) = \sum_{\psi=0}^\infty \mathsf P(X=x\mid N=x+\psi)~\mathsf P(N=x+\psi)$
- $\mathsf P(Y=y) = \sum_{\chi=0}^\infty \mathsf P(Y=y\mid N=\chi+y)~\mathsf P(N=\chi+y)$
- $\mathsf P(X=x, Y=y) = \mathsf P(X=x\mid N=x+y)~\mathsf P(N=x+y)$

Comment: $P(X)=0.38*p_x(k)$ and $P(Y)=0.62*p_y(k)$ Is this correct so far ?
To check the independence of 2 events, i know these 2 formulas:
$P(AandB)=P(A)P(B)$ and $P(A|B)=P(A)$.

Comment: After thinking about it, maby it has something to do with X~Poisson(7) and Y~Poisson(12), since 38% of people buy the product, and 62% don't (I approximated the 7 and 12)

Comment: @Lalous, Yes, but do not approximate. $X\sim\mathcal{Poiss}(7.22)$ because they purchases occur at constant average rate $19*0.38$ per season and the time between subsequent purchases is independent of the times of prior purchases.  Similarly for $Y\sim\mathcal{Poiss}(11.78)$.

Comment: So, now all I have to do is prove that $P(X=x∣N=x+y)=P(X=x)$ ?

Comment: Yes!  In other words: $X$ is the count of 'successes' among $N$ independent Bernoulli trails each with success rate $0.38$; the very definition of a Binomial Distributed Random Variable. $~\therefore~ X\mid N~\sim~\mathcal{Bin}(N, 0.38)$

Comment: Just to make sure, because it looks too simple to be true. In part 2, to maximize his average profit, since 7.22 out of 19 will buy, he should store 7.22 units average ? If yes, how can he store a non natural number.

Comment: I calculated P(X=x) using the equation u gave me, It gives me $e^{-7.22}\frac{7.22^x}{x!}$ , which makes a lot of sens. Now how do i compare it to P(X=x|N=x+y) to prove that they are independent.